# Testing software on windows 8

Tags: testing, windows-8, virtualization

Our company's software product is currently supported on versions of windows between windows XP and windows 7. We will shortly be adding support for windows 8 to that list. In order to do this reliably we need to test properly on windows 8.

There doesnt seem to be any way to virtualize windows 8. Our IT department inform us that running OEM versions of windows 8 in a virtual machine is a breach of microsoft licensing conditions, and the only retail versions available appear to be upgrade versions only. What options do we have for creating a reproducible windows 8 environment in order to complete testing?

Comment: Do you have an MSDN Subscription? Windows 8 and Windows 8 Pro are [available](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/downloads/default.aspx#searchTerm=&ProductFamilyId=481&Languages=en&PageSize=10&PageIndex=0&FileId=0) for testing.

Answer (score 0):

Use non-OEM version. As a person that is actively involved with development of paravirtualized drivers for Windows VMs and their certification with MS I think your IT department is not doing a good job.

Answer (score 0):

You can reproduce Windows 8 in a virtual environment using my favorite free VMware Player. Since the product key and activation in Windows 8 is mandatory and automated, you can use the 90-day trial version of Windows 8 Enterprise as the test version.
Otherwise you can opt for Cloud services like Microsoft Azure’s trial version for limited period of time which should be enough, I guess, for Reliability testing of your application.